# Get an array from a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im getting this:

```
[{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, "IceCube::WeeklyRule", 1, 0]
```

from this:

```
event.recurring.map { |key, value| value }
```

how can I get the `array (day)` and its values?

Comment: what is in `event.recurring`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mrzasa `<% @events.each do |event| %>` `<%= event.recurring.map { |key, value| value } %>`

Comment: nope, please post content of `event.recurring`

Comment: I will asume that `event.recurring` has the first value that you posted, if that's correct, you can take that array like this `event.recurring[0][:day]`

Comment: @mrzasa `{:validations=>{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, :rule_type=>"IceCube::WeeklyRule", :interval=>1, :week_start=>0}`

Comment: `event.recurring[:validations][:day]`

Comment: @max thanks I went with your solution, pretty straight forward! Thanks!!!

Comment: @max how about if I want to split the array into each value?

Comment: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html

Answer (score 0):

```
event.recurring.map { |key, value| value }
```

returns

```
[{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, "IceCube::WeeklyRule", 1, 0]
```

So

```
event.recurring.map { |key, value| value }.first
```

returns

```
{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

If you want just the array of integers, try:

```
event.recurring.map { |key, value| value }.first[:day]
```

Which returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: But the whole step of `.map { |key, value| value }` is completely pointless - just use the correct hash key in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, "IceCube::WeeklyRule", 1, 0]
a.first.values.flatten
```

Comment: Can you explain that further, such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have this:

```
event_recurring = {k1: {:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, k2: "IceCube::WeeklyRule", k3: 1, k4: 0}
```

instead of `.map` you can do:

```
event_recurring.flat_map { |_, v| v[:day] if v.is_a? Hash }.compact
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get day array you can try like this.

```
arr = [{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, "IceCube::WeeklyRule", 1, 0]

arr.first[:day]
```

or

```
event.recurring.map { |key, value| value }.first[:day]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, "IceCube::WeeklyRule", 1, 0]
arr.grep(Hash).first[:day]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr = [1, 0, {:day=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, "IceCube::WeeklyRule"]
arr.grep(Hash).first[:day]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```